# Can I use the Microsoft logo inside the "Sign up with Microsoft" button on my app

Tags: office365api, outlook-api

Since my application integrates with Outlook and the users should sign up via the Microsoft (office365 or Live) sign up page is there any special design guidelines I should follow for the signup button like the ones [required by Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#top_of_page). If not, can I use the Microsoft logo (in terms of legal issues) on my sign-up button like this:
https://www.screencast.com/t/dUjsjZiIB

P.S. Sorry for this question not being particularly technical, but the matter is important for a live com application and I struggled to find anything specific on this around the web.

Comment: Read this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/permissions and https://www.google.com/permissions/trademark/rules.html. Google says Use only Google-approved artwork when using Google's logos and for Microsoft  you can use it as link method, in this case button.

Comment: Thanks Jai. It has some useful information but I couldn't find an answer to my specific question there, which is why I posted here. To be honest those guidelines are a bit too abstract. For example, what does it mean that I can use the logo" by participating in an applicable Link Logo program." How do I apply to participate... I really expected to find some "official" buttons in the Microsoft apps developers documentation.